# Информация из консоли Nodejs/Gulp

Tags: node.js, gulp, консоль

Возникла необходимость для перехвата консольной информации в nodejs/gulp, в основном для логгирования, дело в том что, различные плагины gulp выводят необходимую информацию, например stylelint или gulp-jsbeautifier/gulp-size, различные плагины выводят много информации различными логгерами, fancy-log, winston и др. Переопределение console.log, process.stdout или просто console не даёт ничего, информация получаемая таким перехватом это либо консольный вывод из основного файла gulpfile.js или совершенно пустой лог.

```
var fs  = require('fs');
var ws = fs.createWriteStream('log.txt', { 
        'flags'   : 'w',
        'encoding': 'utf8',
        'mode'    : 0666,
    });

process.stdout.wr = process.stdout.write;
process.stdout.er = process.stderr.write;

process.stdout.write = function(mes, c) {
    ws.write(mes + '\r\n');
    process.stdout.wr(mes, c)   
};

process.stderr.write = function(mes, c) {
    ws.write(mes + '\r\n');
    process.stdout.er(mes, c)   
};
```

В итоге единственный способ который есть для Windows это использовать конструкцию похожую на:
gulp build --dev >> _log/gulp.log & type _log/gulp.log
чтобы информация выводилась и в консоль, и записывалась в файл.
Хотелось бы избежать такой конструкции перед запуском либо автоматизировать её как-то чтобы не приходилось вводить такую лапшу

Answer (score 0):

Если вы используете npm или yarn, вы можете написать в packaje.josn в пакете свои скрипты. Скажем, так:

```
...
"scripts": {
    "build_dev": "gulp build --dev >> _log/gulp.log & type _log/gulp.log",
    "build_prod": "gulp build --prod",
    ...
  },
...
```

После чего, просто вызвать `npm run build_dev`.

[npm run docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script.html)

[yarn run docs (ru)](https://yarnpkg.com/ru/docs/cli/run/)